# Как создать несколько таблиц в Sqlite android?

Tags: java, android, база-данных, sqlite

Есть уже бд с таблицей Tasks(uuid, name, date, list(только что добавил столбец)). Я хочу сделать, чтобы в последнем был uuid из другой таблицы Lists, где есть много списков. 
Проще говоря, как создать новую таблицу в Sqlite и ссылаться на неё из другой таблицы?

Comment: в текущем виде вопроса можно только посоветовать вам что то узнать о связях в реляционных базах данных, в частности в вашем случае видимо о связи "один ко многим" (one to many). Сам вопрос не понятен: вы не знаете, как создать таблицу, как связать несколько таблиц? и не ясно, какая именно связь между ними должна быть установлена. СУБД точная наука и абстрактные "создать и ссылаться" мало помогут вам получить полезный ответ. привидите конкретные примеры структуры таблиц и их желаемых связей

Comment: @pavlofff Я немного разобрался - как я сделал: task(id, title, date, id_list), в свою очередь list(id_list, title). Так правильно будет?

Comment: правильно, только во второй таблице имя колонки не обязательно должно быть таким же, как и в связующей колонке. Вообще в Android колонка с уникальным идентификатором обязательно должна иметь имя *_id* и никак иначе для корректной работы классов Android. То есть ваши таблицы будут:task(_id, title, date, id_list) и list(_id, title). В 4-ую колонку первой пишите значение из 1-ой колонки второй таблицы, строки которой надо связать.

Comment: Но главное - это правильный запрос. Например, чтобы сделать выборку, которая вернет значения из первой таблицы и связанный с ней столбец из второй, запрос будет таким: `SELECT task._id,  task.title, task.date, list.title FROM task, list WHERE task.id_list = list._id`. Для лучшего понимания рекомендую почитать книгу Л. Бейли "Изучаем SQL" она вам сильно поможет понять работу с реляционной БД.

Comment: @pavlofff но я как-то обычными методами обхожусь, без запросов. Может быть ещё не сталкивался. А обязательно по _id? UUID в книге использовался во всех случаях и именно по нему осуществлялся поиск.

Comment: БД должна отдавать полностью подготовленные данные (отфильтрованные, отсортированные, сгрупированные, с реализованными связями и тд), с которыми более не требуется производить никаких модификаций в структуре и ровно в том, объеме, который требуется в данный момент иначе ее использование фактически бессмысленно, в качестве простого хранилища можно использовать средства попроще с обычной записью в файл, как [библиотека paper](https://github.com/pilgr/Paper) , например.

Comment: в андроид колонка с уникальным идентификатором обязательно должна называться _id, такое требование системы. "обхожусь обычными методами" - вы обрабатываете данные из БД в java-коде? это самое плохое, что можно было придумать при работе с базами данных. java-код на порядки медленее, столько же менее эфективен в возможностях обработки и вообще это как у вас современное роботизированное производство, на котором вы используете только погрузчик, чтобы со склада привезти все материалы и потом сидите на стульчике, напильником пилите, перекладываете там что то, таскаете на себе .. а конвеер в пыли уже